# BeautifulSoup, dont fix html

Tags: beautifulsoup, lxml

Given the following html

```
html = """
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>
        <p>
            Hello World
        </p>
    </p>

    <body>
    </html>
"""
```

When I pass it to BeautifulSoup using lxml and prettify it, this is the output I get

```
print BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
   Hello World
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Because the `<p>` tags can't be nested since its invalid HTML, they are closed when parsed.
Is there a way to ignore this and treat them as nestable?

I can't parse it as `xml` since I'd want to use css selectors which I can't as an XML

Any way to configure lxml to ignore invalid html?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html.parser`. But in `html.parser` a new `body` gets added.

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: html = """<html>
   ...:     <body>
   ...:
   ...:     <p>
   ...:         <p>
   ...:             Hello World
   ...:         </p>
   ...:     </p>
   ...:
   ...:     <body>
   ...:     </html>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [4]: soup.prettify()
Out[4]: '<html>\n <body>\n  <p>\n   <p>\n    Hello World\n   </p>\n  </p>\n  <body>\n  </body>\n </body>\n</html>'

In [5]: print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   <p>
    Hello World
   </p>
  </p>
  <body>
  </body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Using `html5` parser. A `head` tag gets added

```
n [11]: html = """<html>
    ...:     <body>
    ...:
    ...:     <p>
    ...:         <p>
    ...:             Hello World
    ...:         </p>
    ...:     </p>
    ...:
    ...:     <body>
    ...:     </html>"""

In [12]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5")

In [13]: print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
   Hello World
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```